# List latest revision of all files in SVN with commit message

Tags: svn, visualsvn

What I want is just a simple list of all file in the repository (recursive) next to the latest commit message.

E.g.
File A   Some bug has been fixed
File B   Something has been added here
...

In case that helps: Repository is hosted on a Windows server machine through VisualSVN

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you run into any specific issues while trying those things?

Comment: svn list --recursive gives me a list of all files but as a minimum I'd also need to list the latest commit message next to each file. Haven't found anything that does that in the documentation.

Comment: There isn't anything in the documentation because it's not a feature of Subversion, nor is it how Subversion works. You'll have to script this yourself.

Comment: Why do you want this? This information is available in the commit itself.

Comment: one repository is used to version control PDF documents (internal procedures). Whenever a new revision is released, we commit it over the previous one and as comment we write revision number and effective date.
And now it would be nice to be able to produce a list with all procedures together with their latest revision and effective date.